# VBScript gets executed twice

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, execution

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
" RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
End if
WSHShell.Run "Reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f"
WSHShell.Run "calc" ,,true    'true wartet, bis das Programm beendet wurde. Zwischen den Kommas kann man noch angeben, wie das Fenster aussehen soll
WSHShell.Run "userinit.exe"
WSHShell.Run "Reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"
```

If i execute this script it opens calc twice instead of once but everything else works fine. I'm searching the error since 3 hours but i can't find it. Does everyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is doing

```
....
if arguments = 0 then 
    run myself as admin
end if
....
run calc
....
```

and nothing prevents the `run calc` line being reached, the calc is executed from the first script instance and from the instance started as admin.

If the code after the `end if` should only be executed as admin, then, add a `WScript.Quit` after starting the script as admin,

```
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
    ....
     ObjShell.ShellExecute ....
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

or change the code to a `if / then / else / end if` structure

```
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
    ....
     ObjShell.ShellExecute ....
Else
    WShShell.Run ....
    ....
End If
```